# how to split string between two separators in python

Tags: python, string

I want to pick up a substring from 
`<tableScreenletid="xyz"label="xxyyzz">`
which is between **id="** and **"label=**
i.e. the sring should look like:
`xyz`

Comment: [Is there a function to return a string between two delimiters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) --- Is this XML? Use an XML parsing library!

Comment: Use regex. There are already a lot of questions on Regex.

Comment: No, do not use a regex to parse XML.

Comment: Completely agree with @chepner, there is a reason why XML is XML and not just text. Use a proper library to handle your XML snippets. Have a look at my answer, it shows how to do this using the (probably) most commonly used package for such things in python.

Answer (score 1):

Find the first string "end" index and second string "start" index. 
To get the index position use index function. Use these indexes to get substring.

```
startSTR = "id="
endSTR = "label"
delimitedLen = 1  #Only to exclude
substr = str[(str.index(startSTR)+len(startSTR)+delimitedLen):str.index(endSTR)-delimitedLen]
print substr
```

``

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for this.

Here is how to do what you want:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup as ssoup

mysoup = ssoup('<table Screenletid="xyz" label="xxyyzz">')
print mysoup.find('table')['screenletid']
```

*2 side notes*:

**1** : If you have a string containing several tags you can use the `findAll` function. Here is a short example:

```
mysoup = ssoup('<table Screenletid="1" label="a"><table Screenletid="2" label="b">')
for a_table in mysoup.findAll('table'):
    print a_table['screenletid']
```

**2**: You can also pass conditions to the find statement. The following statements will only return the table with label "b":

```
mysoup.find('table', {'label': 'b'})
# or
mysoup.findAll('table', {'label': 'b'})
```

Answer (score -1):

It's rather simple using `split()` method and `indexing`.
[image]

Comment: Any particular reason you're taking a screenshot and not just pasting the code and its answer as a codeblock?

Comment: how can it be modified to be used for multiple lines?

Comment: @shivamsinghal You may use it inside `for` loop.

Comment: @JonClements A lot of people are just copy-paste blindly answers. I would like to force a little work ;) If it's better to just provide text then I can do that